# How do I execute a GoApp Binary on Windows - specifically oauth2l

Tags: windows, go, google-oauth, google-home

I have downloaded windows_amd.tgz from Github for the oauth2l project. I then used 7-Zip to extract the tar and used it again to extract a file called oauth2l.  This file has no extension but is suppose to be a executable binary that I can run on Windows.  I tried renaming it with a .exe but that doesn't seem to work.

The question is how do I run this binary or am I doing something else incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track. Follow the steps below to run this binary.

- Download https://storage.googleapis.com/oauth2l/latest/windows_amd64.tgz
- Extract until you see the file `oauth2l`
- Add the extension `.exe` to the file `oauth2l`
- Open a terminal (Powershell or Command Prompt)
- Navigate to the directory with the the file `oauth2l.exe`

  - For example, `cd path\to\directory`
- Run `.\oauth2l.exe -help` and you should see the help message appear.

How were you running this before? Were you double-clicking the file? You need to run this in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to rename anything, https://storage.googleapis.com/oauth2l/latest/windows_amd64.tgz file contains `oauth2l.exe` file:

```
$ curl -o windows_amd64.tgz https://storage.googleapis.com/oauth2l/latest/windows_amd64.tgz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 2973k  100 2973k    0     0  2233k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 2248k


$ tar tvf windows_amd64.tgz 
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   root        0 Jun 29 14:31 windows_amd64/
-rwxr-xr-x  0 root   root  7621120 Jun 29 14:31 windows_amd64/oauth2l.exe
```

Extract `oauth2l.exe` file from windows_amd64.tgz with 7-Zip and run it as-is.